# Vuetify: Problem with buttons in pagination

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, submit, vuetify.js

Using the Vuetify v-pagination we get a bunch of buttons

```
<form action="">
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <v-text-field label="Insert text and press enter"></v-text-field><br />
    <v-pagination
      v-model="page"
      :length="6"
    ></v-pagination>
  </div>
</form>
```

Our problem is, that we have to wrap everything in a form. But the v-pagination is output as `<button>` instead of `<button type="button">`. This means pressing Enter while typing in the field, reloads the page.

Is there any way to change this or prevent the submit? Or to tell Vuetify to use `type="button"`?

I'd also like to avoid submit-handlers, preventDefaults or changing the button-type after load.

[Link to Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVBjyd?&editors=101)

Comment: See answers there in duplicate e.g. `<form @submit.prevent>`. Or you don't want to prevent it? Perhaps I misunderstood something?

Comment: Why do you "have to wrap everything in a form."   For Vue the `<form>` element is definitely not necessary.  Or similarly do you absolutely need the pagination inside the form?

Comment: @Traxo Thanks, I'd seen the question, but missed the submit.prevent, I thought the only solution was to add prevents on the inputs (which I didn't want). This solved it, thanks! I'll close this question and upvote the other question.

Comment: @skribe we use v-form for validation, that's why we need the form-wrap.